# Could string variable in vb.net be a reference in SQL Where statement?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Could anyone help me with the following WHERE statement ? I want  to make bn as reference in WHERE statement.

This is whats in my code:

```
Public bn As String = ""  

Dim SQLStatement As String = "UPDATE patient SET number_of_bottles='" & lblBottle.Text & "'  WHERE bednumber=bn ORDER BY patient_ID DESC LIMIT 1"
```

During the program, bn is an identifier where I would know which bednumber I will gonna access.

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Don't use string concatenation because you're open for SQL-Injection, instead use parameters.

Comment: See how the number of bottles is included in the SQL statement? You could use the same technique to include the bed number, that would be a good start. Then you should learn about parameterized queries, because as Tim mentioned, string concatenation is not secure.

Comment: how can i do that? thanks! sorry I am new in vb.net as well as MySql. Thanks!

Comment: I will SET bednumber='" & bn & "' WHERE bednumber=bn ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Edited to use MySQL-specific objects rather than generic ODBC)

```
    Dim bn As String = ""       ' Set this to some value in your code
    Dim bottles As Integer = 0  ' Set this to some value in your code
    Dim SQLStatement As String = "UPDATE patient SET number_of_bottles = @bottles WHERE bednumber = @bednumber"

    Using cnn As New MySqlConnection("Connection string here")
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(SQLStatement, cnn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("bottles", bottles)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("bednumber", bn)
        cnn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cnn.Close()
    End Using
```

Alternate version, creating `MySqlParameter` objects by hand -- note that you'll need to create the parameter objects, set their values, then add them to the parameters collection of the `MySqlCommand` object

```
Using cnn As New MySqlConnection("Connection string here")
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(SQLStatement, cnn)
    Dim pBottles As New MySqlParameter("bottles", bottles)
    Dim pBedNumber As New MySqlParameter("bednumber", bn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pBottles)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pBedNumber)
    cnn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cnn.Close()
End Using
```

Comment: There is an error where AddWithValue is not member of MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter   
I am using MySqlConnection and MySqlCommand

Comment: @catherine-takishima, is sounds like you're trying to use `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter` -- note that in my code above, there's no reason to do so, as the `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue`, which is part of the `Command` object, creates the parameter and adds it to the parameter collection of the `Command` object.

Comment: Is that different with .Parameters.Add("bottles", bottles) ?

Comment: As with most things in .NET, there are usually _many_ different ways to accomplish the same thing. The two examples I have above do the same thing -- create parameter objects, name them, and append them to the parameters collection of the Command object. The only difference is whether you're using a method exposed by the Parameters collection of the Command object (.AddWithValue) or by creating the Parameter object separately and adding it in. In most cases, AddWithValue works fine, but both get you to the same place in the end...